# Intermittent Authentication Against Active Directory from Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, active-directory

I'm trying to build a website where employees at my company can enter their Windows Domain credentials to log in. I am running an Express backend that looks like this:

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const passport = require('passport');
const LdapStrategy = require('passport-ldapauth');

// initialize server
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false,
}));

// initialize passport
app.use(passport.initialize());

// define Active Directory connection settings
const getOptions = (request, callback) => {
    process.nextTick(() => {
        const username = request.query.username;
        const password = request.query.password;
        const options = {
            server: {
                url: 'LDAP://internal.mycompany.com',
                bindDN: username + '@internal.mycompany.com',
                bindCredentials: password,
                searchBase: 'DC=internal,DC=mycompany,DC=com',
                searchFilter: '(samaccountname=' + username + ')',
            },
        };
        callback(null, options);
    });
};

// register passport
passport.use(new LdapStrategy(getOptions));

// respond to GET requests with authentication
app.get('/ldap', passport.authenticate('ldapauth', {session: false}), (request, response) => {
    response.setHeader('ContentType', 'application/json');
    response.send(JSON.stringify({
        success: true,
    }));
});

// run server on port 3001
app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log('Express server running on port 3001.');
});
```

I enter `http://localhost:3001/ldap?username=myusername&password=mypassword` into my web browser, and I get **one of 3 different responses**.

**Response A:**

```
{"success":true}
```

This indicates that everything worked as planned. Great. This happens roughly 20% of the time.

**Response B:**

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.11.10.165:389
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)
```

This is probably just because I am spamming requests again and again sometimes. Doesn't happen very often.

**Response C:**

```
OperationsError: 00000000: LdapErr: DSID-0C090627, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, vece
    at messageCallback (/c/.../node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:1419:45)
    at Parser.onMessage (/c/.../node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:1089:14)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Parser.write (/c/.../node_modules/ldapjs/lib/messages/parser.js:111:8)
    at Socket.onData (/c/.../node_modules/ldapjs/lib/client/client.js:1076:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
```

This is the most common response. This is a mystifying error. Everything I read online says that supplying `bindDN` and `bindCredentials` will allow the activedirectory package to do its initial bind and then that should make it work.

I have also tried the `passport-activedirectory` and `activedirectory` npm packages, but with very similar results (passport-activedirectory never worked and activedirectory had the same sometimes-working behavior). I also tried activedirectory2, with no luck.

[All](https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory/issues/69)
[these](https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory/issues/78)
[different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32293689/bind-error-with-ldap-authentication-using-passport-and-node-js)
[links](https://github.com/vesse/passport-ldapauth/issues/59)
have been helpful in getting this far, but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong at this point. Especially when it works sometimes. My internet connection is very stable, so I don't think that's the issue.

**Question:**

Why am I seeing this intermittent behavior and is there a solution? If not, what other options do I have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was connecting to `'LDAP://internal.mycompany.com'`, when I should have been connecting to `'LDAP://LOGON_M0103.internal.mycompany.com'`. Apparently that's the name of the actual domain controller.

For anyone else that has this issue, I found the answer by using AD Explorer and looking at the root of the connection, where it said the domain controller's name in square brackets. Also, there's an entry `OU=Domain Controllers`, and that has `CN=LOGON_M0103` within it inside the AD.

I'm still puzzled by why it was even working at all with just `'LDAP://internal.mycompany.com'`.